# Rosenlicht Chapter 1 Problem 11 Unbounded Set

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I've been working on this problem for over an hour. It is from Maxwell Rosenlicht's text book "Introduction to Analysis" in the first chapter before limits are discussed. I will state the claim, show what I worked to so far, and explain where I am stuck.

Problem: Prove that if $a\in \mathbb R, a>1$, then the set $\{a,a^2,a^3,...\}$ is not bounded from above. (Hint: First find a positive integer n such that $a>1+\frac1n$ and prove that $a^n>(1+\frac1n)^n\ge2$).

For the sake of following the hint he gave me I attempted to prove that claim. Which I will now demonstrate. However, I feel that it may possibly be incorrect. Nevertheless, should my proof of the hint be correct I still do not understand how it is supposed to help me prove the original claim about the set given not being bounded from above.

Lemma 1: If $a>1$ and $n$ is a positive integer, then $a^n>(1+\frac1n)^n\ge2$.

Proof: Following with a proof by induction we prove our base case.

Base Case: Because $a-1>0$ we can say that there exists an integer $n_0$ such that $a-1>\frac{1}{n_0}$ or after adding one to both sides $a>\frac{1}{n_0} +1$ Now, if we let $n_0=n=1$, then we have $2<a$.

Inductive Step: First note that $(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^n<(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ because, $n<n+1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{n} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n+1}+1 < \frac{1}{n} +1 \Rightarrow (\frac{1}{n+1}+1)^n < (\frac{1}{n} +1)^n$. 
Now, we assume that $(\frac{1}{k} +1)^k < a^k$ for all positive integers $k$. But, $(\frac{1}{k+1}+1)^k < (\frac{1}{k} +1)^k$ so $(\frac{1}{k+1}+1)^k<a^k$ or simply $(\frac{1}{k+1}+1)<a$. However, if $(\frac{1}{k+1}+1)^k<a^k$ and $(\frac{1}{k+1}+1)<a$, then $(\frac{1}{k+1}+1)^k(\frac{1}{k+1}+1)<aa^k$ or $(\frac{1}{k+1}+1)^{k+1}<a^{k+1}$.

I spent a lot of time trying to figure this proof out, and then again typing it on here so I hope it is correct, but I feel somewhat nervous about it.Any feedback on my proof would be grateful. Also, any advice on where I should go to prove the original statement about the unbounded set after finishing this lemma would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can not prove your Lemma 1 as stated because you are letting n be any positive integer.  You must choose n to be sufficiently large.  E.g., if a = 1.1 and n = 2 then your lemma doesn't hold.  Once you have done this the induction step will follow immediately.

Comment: So my inductive step is correct, but not my base case?

Answer (score 1):

I love this book and remember doing this problem.

Use the binomial theorem. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$\left( 1 +  \frac{1}{n} \right)^n = 1 + \binom{n}{1} \left(\frac{1}{n} \right)^1+\binom{n}{2} \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^2 + ... > 1 + \binom{n}{1}\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) = 1 + 1 = 2$

As for the second part, you assume it is bounded so that there is a $B$ such that $a^k \leq B \: \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$.
How can you pick a natural number $k$ so that it works?

We can find a $n$ such that $ a^n > 2$.

Well, how can you pick $k$ so that $2^k > B$?

Now, given that $a^n > 2$, what happens if you raise $a^n$ to this $k$?